# Javascript Posting to Window

Tags: javascript, arrays, post

I have built up a multiple dimentional array in javascript called myData,
I also have a code which opens up a new window and loads the page.

How would I go about Posting the myData array to the new window?

```
var url = './multi_quote.php';
var win = window.open(url, 'Show Data', 'directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,width=500,height=600');
    if (win.focus) { win.focus(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post directly through the URL parameters:

```
var url = './multi_quote.php?param1='+JSON.stringify(arrayObj);
```

Or, even better, you can read the array from the child popup window:

```
var dataArray = window.opener.myData;
```

So, you need not send the array to the request at all.

Comment: Thanks, I am surpised I did not considor the frist, it is the most simplest option and should work fine for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
   function popupwindow (id) {

    var url = './multi_quote.php?quote_id='+id+'';
    var win = window.open(url, 'Show Data', 'directories=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,width=500,height=600');
        if (win.focus) { win.focus(); }

    }

<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow(1)">Quote 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="popupwindow(2)">Quote 2</a>
```

You mean like this i think.